# Sending Azure Application Insights data to Event Hub

Tags: azure, azure-application-insights, azure-eventhub

I have a static dot net web application with application insights sdk. How do I send application insights data to Azure Event Hub? I have successfully used the Azure Continuous Export feature but I would rather like to send the telemetry data to the Event Hub.

Answer (score 1):

To explicitly send data to eventhub you will need to use EventHub SDK, which is currently available in .NET/C#, Java, REST, and Node.js. For your case which is a web application, sending via REST APIs might be the easiest way. Take a look at API reference for more information: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn790674.aspx

One catch is that receiving events is not currently supported using REST, you would still need a .NET or Java application to be on the receive side.

Comment: I have experimented with Event Hub SDK separately. I guess my question is how do you retrieve app insights telemetry data programatically and push it to event hub for a dot net MVC web application? Because, by default it sends telemetry data to azure app insights service from there you can run continuous export. How do I programmatically retrieve app insights telemetry data and then send it to event hub? For example, where would you place your code and how i.e. View, Model, Controller? The default configuration is a black box to me.

Comment: There might be a way to do it using the sample App insights Java script snippet. But that script takes an instrumentation key authenticates and pushes the events. I am not entirely sure how to modify the script to instead use Event Hub.  
http://apmtips.com/blog/2015/03/18/javascript-snippet-explained/

Comment: What you described sounds like a output redirection feature, I'm not sure if AppInisghts currently supports it. Let me ask AppInsight team and get back to you when I have an answer.

Answer (score 1):

@greypanda,

As you know Continuous Export currently only exports Application Insights to blob storage, from which you can pick up the data for use in any workstream you want. Exporting directly in an Event Hub is something that could be a future feature, so please log this at our UserVoice site: https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/357324-application-insights.

We will also have a set of REST APIs for Application Insights soon (see https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/357324-application-insights/suggestions/4999529), which might help you.

I would like to learn more about your scenario so I can better help you in this instance and improve our export and API features. Feel free to reply here or if you want, shoot me a mail offline.

Thank you

Dale Koetke (dalek@microsoft.com)

Answer (score 0):

We don't really support that. It's a lot easier to let the SDK send the data to App Insights portal, then you can use Continuous Export to move it out into Storage. If you want, you can [use Stream Analytics](https://azure.microsoft.com/documentation/articles/app-insights-code-sample-export-sql-stream-analytics/) to move it from there.

What do you plan to ultimately do with the data? (I mean, why event hub...?)

Comment: We do not want to use continuous export. We would like to send the telemetry data to event hub. Event hub is scalable and more reliable why not event hub? Are you definitely sure that is not possible? How about a java script call to the event hub from the web page?

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for a common logging framework - which can be configured to send data to "whatever data destination" you want to - you should consider looking at [log4net](http://logging.apache.org/log4net/release/features.html).

[Here's](http://microsoftintegration.guru/2015/03/09/log4net-azure-service-bus-event-hubs/) a good implementation of log4net-appender for EventHubs.